# R-snippet Error: lazy-load database 'P' is corrupt

Tags: r, knime

I'm getting an error in the "R snippet" and while it is working perfectly in RStudio:

```
Error: lazy-load database 'P' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: restarting interrupted promise evaluation 
2: internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

This is the code that works in RStudio but not in Knime.

```
install.packages("stringr")
library(stringr)
bad_text = c("This", " example ", "has several ", " whitespaces ")
# remove whitespaces on the left side
str_trim(bad_text, side = "left")`
```

How can I trace where this error is coming from?

Thanks!

Comment: Restarting Knime has solved the issue for me. How do I close the question?

Comment: You can answer your question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simply restarting Knime has solved the issue for me.